# How to add descriptive attribute when using ManyToManyField in django?

Tags: python, django, database

I am just trying to learn django. Sorry if this is a silly question.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/
I was reading this documentation on ManyToManyField, it talks about two models Articles and Publishers.
`    from django.db import models

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["title"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["headline"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline`
```

Articles has a ManyToManyField 'publishers'. In the document it says the association table is created by django. Now how do I add descriptive attributes for example 'published date'?

I have read this documentation. I want to know if there is a way to add descriptive attribute when using ManyToManyField.

EDIT: An article in each publication has different published date.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `published_date` field to `Article` model

```
class Article(models.Model):
   headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
   published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention, the published_date would be different for each publications for the same article. Would your answer still work for that case.